# What will be a good book to solve exercises from in ergodic theory?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, ergodic-theory

I am now using Walter's book; it has no exercises.

I am a graduate student with reasonable background.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The title of a question should never its first sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ergodic Theory with a view towards Number Theory* by Manfred Einsiedler and Thomas Ward is a great book with plenty of exercises (and selected hints if needed), even if you're not so interested in the number theory side.